# Angular - Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular-12, I have this code:

```js
editForm: FormGroup;

onSubmit() {
  // Stop processing form submission if form data is invalid //
  if (this.editForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  //  processing form submission data to server //
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('heading', this.editForm.get('heading').value);
  formData.append('title', this.editForm.get('title').value);
  formData.append('image', this.editForm.get('image').value);
  formData.append('description', this.editForm.get('description').value);
  formData.append('id', this.editForm.get('id').value);

  this.http.post(this.serverUrl + 'updateAbout', formData).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.router.navigate(['admin/about']).then(() => this.showToasterSuccess(res.message));
    },
    error => this.router.navigate(['admin/about']).then(() => this.showToasterError(error[0].message))
  );

}
```

We got this error:

> Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

and this is highlighted:

> formData.append('heading', this.editForm.get('heading').value);

I applied some of the similar solutions in stackoverflow, but none is working.

For instance, in tsconfig.json, I added "strictNullChecks": true  to:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
   "strictInjectionParameters": true,
   "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
   "strictTemplates": true,
   "strictNullChecks": true
 }
```

But the problem is still not resolved.

How do I get it sorted out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formData.append('heading', this.editForm.get('heading').value);
                                                       ^
```

Angular cannot be sure that a form control exists with a name `heading`, which is why the `get` method returns an `AbstractControl | null`. If you're sure that you're not making a typo with `'heading'` and you're sure that the result will be non-null, you can use a **non-null assertion operator**.

```
formData.append('heading', this.editForm.get('heading')!.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the formGroup as shown below

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      heading: new FormControl('heading'),
      title: new FormControl('title'),
      image: new FormControl('image'),
      description: new FormControl('description'),
      id: new FormControl('id'),
    });
  }
```

In onSubmit :

```
  onSubmit() {
    // Stop processing form submission if form data is invalid //
    if (this.editForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
  
    //  processing form submission data to server //
    const formData = new FormData();
  
    formData.append('heading', this.editForm.value.heading);
    console.log(this.editForm.value.heading);
  }
```

regards,